# Call ios-charts fromObj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-charts

I try to use ios-chart (Swift framework) from my objective-c project.
And I don't use storyboard or UI-designer. I program.  :-)

Is there anyone who can hint me how to open a LineChart or other chart from my UIViewController?
My best guess so far is to create a subclass from UIViewController and programatically add a BarChartView provided with my data that should be plotted.
I thought I would find a UIViewController in interface folder but havn't done that.
Any example or hint is appreciated!

Kind regards.
Jan Gifvars

Comment: Are you asking how to call Swift code from Objective-c? Or are you asking how to make a Chart?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts
Repository contains ChartsDemo folder with real examples written in objective-c. You can use it as an example.
If you want to install this library as pod using cocoapods, then you to include `use_frameworks` in your pod file.

Answer (score 0):

swift is callable from Obj-c and vice versa, guarenteed by apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

btw, if you need to support iOS 7, use ios-charts source code directly.